# Unable to Populate Dynamic Drop Down List Using AJAX Request on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Good day,

I have multiple drop down list that I must populate using AJAX Request but I was unable to do it.

I don't know where is my error because I'm new in using AJAX. I was able to research in the internet but unluckily I can't fully understand their explanation.

Can someone explain to me.. What Am I doing wrong here.

Advance thanks to those who will reply to my thread.

By the way these are my codes on my encoding page.

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function populateDropDown(choice){

var httpxml;
try{
    httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

catch (e){
    try {
        httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e){
        try{
            httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e){
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function stateChanged(){
    if (httpxml.readystate==4){
        var myObject = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);

        for (j=document.get_forms.province.options.length-1;j>=0;j--){
            document.get_forms.province.remove(j);
        }

        var province1=myObject.value.province1;
        var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
        optn.text = 'Select Region First';
        optn.value = '';
        document.get_forms.province.options.add(optn);

        for(i=0;i<myObject.province.length;i++){

            var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
            optn.text = myObject.province[i];
            optn.value = myObject.province[i];
            document.get_forms.province.options.add(optn);

            if (optn.value==province1){
                var k = i + 1;
                document.get_forms.province.options[k].selected=true;
            }

        }

        for (j=document.get_forms.municipality.options.length;j>=0;j--){
            document.get_forms.municipality.remove(j);
        }
            var municipality1 = myObject.value.municipality1;

            for (i=0;i<myObject.municipality1.length;i++){

                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optn.text = myObject.municapility[i];
                optn.value = myObject.municipality[i];
                document.get_forms.municipality.options.add(optn);

                if (optn.value==municapility1){
                    document.get_forms.municipality.options[i].selected = true;
                }

            }

        for (j=document.get_forms.barangay.options.length;j>=0;j--){
            document.get_forms.barangay.remove(j);
        }
            var barangay1 = myObject.value.barangay1;

            for (i=0;i<myObject.barangay1.length;i++){

                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optn.text = myObject.barangay[i];
                optn.value = myObject.barangay[i];
                document.get_forms.barangay.options.add(optn);

                if (optn.value==barangay1){
                    document.get_forms.barangay.options[i].selected = true;
                }
            }

            var url = "populate.php";
            var region = get_forms.region.value;
            if (choice != 's1'){
                var province = get_forms.province.value;
                var municipality = get_forms.municipality.value;
                var barangay = get.forms.barangay.value;

            }
            else{
                var province = '';
                var municipality = '';
                var barangay = '';
            }

            url = url + "?region="+region;
            url = url + "&province="+province;
            url = url + "&municipality="+municipality;
            url = url + "$barangay="+barangay;
            url = url + "&id="+Math.random();

            get_forms.st.value = province;

            httpxml.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
            httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
            httpxml.send(null);

    }
   }
 }

 </script>
 </head>

 <fieldset>
 <form name='get_forms' action='get_forms.php' method='post'>
  Region :  <select name='region' id='region_id'        onChange="populateDropDown(s1);" required>
            <option value=''> Please Select A Region</option>

            <?php
                require 'config.php';

                $sql='SELECT DISTINCT region FROM roster';                  
                foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['region'];?>"><?php echo $row['region'];?></option>
            <?php   }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type=text name=st value=0><br><br>
  Province : <select name='province' id='province_id'   onChange="populateDropDown(s2);" required>
            <option value="">Please Select Region First</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>    
    Municipality :  <select name='municipality' id='municipality_id' onChange="populateDropDown(s3);" required>
                <option value="">Please Select Province First</option>
            </select>
        <br><br>
      Barangay : <select name='barangay' id='barangay_id' onChange="populateDropDown(s4);" required>
            <option value=""> Please Select Municipality First </option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
   Period:  <select name='period' id='period_id' required>
            <option value=''> Please Select Compliance Period </option>
            <?php
                require 'config.php';

                $sql='SELECT DISTINCT period FROM compliance';
                foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['period'];?>"><?php echo   $row['period'];?></option>
            <?php   }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br><br>
  Form Type:    <select name='form_type' id='form_type_id' required>
            <option value=''> Select Form Type </option>
            <?php
                require 'config.php';

                $sql='SELECT DISTINCT form_type FROM compliance ORDER BY   form_type ASC';
                foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['form_type'];?>"><?php echo $row['form_type'];?></option>
            <?php   }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br><br>

            <input type='submit' value='GET FORMS'>
        </form>

</fieldset>
```

And these are my codes in my populate.php Page.

```
<?php

 require 'config.php'


 $region = $_GET['region'];
$province1 = $_GET['province'];
$municipality1 = $_GET['municipality'];
$barangay1 = $_GET['barangay'];

$sql_prov = "SELECT DISTINCT province FROM roster  WHERE region ='$region'";
 $query=$conn->prepare($sql_prov);
 $query->execute();
  $province= $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

  $sql_mun = "SELECT DISTINCT municipality FROM roster WHERE province =   '$province1";
 $query=$conn->prepare($sql_mun);
 $query->execute();
 $municipality = $query->fetchALL (PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

 $sql_bar = "SELECT DISTINCT barangay FROM roster WHERE municipality = '$municipality1' AND province = '$province1'";
 $query=$conn->prepare ($sql_bar);
 $query->execute();
 $barangay = $query->fetchALL (PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

 $main = array('province'=>$province,'municipality'=>$municipality,'barangay'=>$barangay,'value'=>array("province1"=>"$province1","municipality1"=>"$municipality1","barangay1"=>"$barangay1"));
 echo json_encode($main); 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just give you some idea how Ajax work. and you need to change the output of Ajax.php to return your options from database.

```
<select id="select1">
<option></option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
</select>
<select id="select3">
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change', "#select1", function()
var variable = $("#select1").val();
var action = 'get_select2_options';
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:{action:action: variable:variable},
        success: function(data){
         $("#select2").html(data);
        }
  });
});
$(document).on('change', "#select2", function()
var variable = $("#select2").val();
var action = 'get_select3_options';
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:{action:action: variable:variable},
        success: function(data){
         $("#select3").html(data);
        }
  });
});
</script>
```

AJAX:

```
<?php
if($_POST['action']=='get_select2_options'){
echo '<option>2-1</option><option>2-2</option>';
}
if($_POST['action']=='get_select3_options'){
echo '<option>3-1</option><option>3-2</option>';
}

?>
```